# Best Practice To Manage One To Many Insertions on Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

We're currently developing a .Net Core console application which consumes a web service to fetch data and inserts it to a database asynchronously.

Web service returns an object - to make the problem simple let's call it **Orders** - has a **Country**, **Date** and **Ordered By** fields. In our database we have a **Countries** and **Orders** table with 1 to Many relationship.

When the app starts it stores the country list in a static List property. As a new Order from web service is returned, country field is checked if exist in the current List property to get Id field from it. If it doesn't exist, a new record is inserted to the database and List property is updated with a helper method. This scenario works without any problem in single thread. However when we make the web service requests and update the database asyncronously, each async Task updates List property independently and that causes multiple country values with the same name.

Is there a best practice to keep country list updated only when a new record is inserted and prevent inserting the same values by different Tasks?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a best practice to keep country list updated only when a new record is inserted and prevent inserting the same values by different Tasks?

Yes.  Put a [unique index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes#index-uniqueness) on the Country entity's Name property.  Then when you attempt to add a duplicate Country, it will fail and you can retrieve the ID of the existing country instead.